# How to print python output alongside

Tags: python, printing, formatting

**Want to print python output alongside**

I have two variables *ke* and *qs*. I want to print them alongside.

**The value of ke is** :

```
                     00:00:00.000 -->

                     00:00:10.000 -->

                     00:00:15.000 -->

                     00:00:23.000 -->

                     00:00:28.000 -->
```

**The value of qs is** :

```
                     00:00:00.000

                     00:00:00.000

                     00:00:00.000

                     00:00:00.000

                     00:00:00.000
```

**I want to print it like**:

```
                     00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:00.000

                     00:00:10.000 --> 00:00:00.000

                     00:00:15.000 --> 00:00:00.000

                     00:00:23.000 --> 00:00:00.000

                     00:00:28.000 --> 00:00:00.000
```

**Please tell me how could I print like this in python**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `f-string`:

```
print(f"{ke} --> {qs}")
```